# Google Maps On Click To Market ScrollTo Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, scroll

I have been pulling my hair out and have tried everything. I will have a number of markers which when the user clicks will take them to a scrollable box and bring more info about the location they have clicked on. This info will be scrollable as it will be placed on a modal which will have limited space.

Right now currently when you click on a marker it is clearly on taking you to a different location and when you click again on the same marker it jumps so it is almost like it's random. Has anyone any ideas what I could try to resolve this please check my fiddle which clearly demonstrates the issue thanks.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
   var elem = $(marker.url);
   $('#container').animate({
       scrollTop: elem.offset().top
   }, 1000 );
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/nishpatel/b5rewzn4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sbrwvd2o/.

There were two problems:

1. `var marker` will be overwritten each time while you're looping through `markers` array. And event listener may be added to incorrect marker
2. element.offset().top value is changing when we scroll `#container`.

So, please review new fiddle. Hope it helps.

Comment: @user2200113, no problem.